# How to append prefix and suffix to input value Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to append prefix and suffix to a input value. for example my prefix is ABC and my suffix is DEF, now when an user type something to input then I want to append ABC-USERVAL-DEF that is (Prefix-user input-Suffix).Please help me out.
I have tried something like this.

```js
$("#input").on("keyup", function() {
  var prefix = 'ABC-'
  var suffix= '-DEF'
  var final = prefix + $(this).val() + suffix;
  $(this).val('');
  $(this).val(final);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id="input" val=''>
```

Comment: Why do want to do this @Anish? This does not seem like a good UX. If you still want to do this, You can have a default value on the input for `ABC-` and then user can start typing. After that using `onBlur` you can attach the suffix.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/ew4vnjc8/

Comment: You are using `keyup` so the logic happens every time. Try changing `keyup` to `change`, now this will happen only when you done entering in `input` but again it will get problem if you need to edit the input value.

Comment: @shrys Thank you it is working. everyone thanks for the input and help I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank @shrys for the answer and that solves my problems for now.

```js
$("#input").on("keyup", function(e) {
  var prefix = 'ABC-';
  var suffix = '-DEF';
  var val = $(this).val().replace(prefix, '').replace(suffix, '');
  var final = prefix + val + suffix;
  $(this).val(final);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id="input" val=''>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used @shrys code and enhance that code for backspace.

```js
$("#input").on("keyup", function(e) {
  var prefix = 'ABC-';
  var suffix = '-DEF';
  var val = $(this).val().replace(prefix, '').replace(suffix, '');
  var final = prefix + val + suffix;
  $(this).val(final);
});

$("#input").on("keydown", function(e) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
  var prefix = 'ABC-';
  var suffix = '-DEF';
  if( key == 8 || key == 46 ){
    var val = $(this).val().replace(prefix, '').replace(suffix, '');
    $(this).val(val);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id="input" val=''>
```

credits to @shrys

Answer (score 0):

```js
// I think there's a little bit of that with chang
$("#input").on("change", function (e) {
  let value = $(this).val();
  const prefix = 'ABC-';
  const suffix = '-DEF';
  value = value.replace(/(^ABC-)|(-DEF$)/g, '');
  $(this).val(prefix + value + suffix);
});
```